# Rails 3 - Set table_name_prefix based on subdomain

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I currently have a model named Post which is currently using the default table name of posts. I am looking to change this so that it will use the subdomain as a prefix to the default, so essentially set it at the start of each page request.

The table_name_prefix looks like it will allow me to do this easily, however I need to find a way to make request.subdomain available to the class. Does anyone have any suggestions on the best way to do this?

Thanks,
Scott

Comment: It looks like [the `table_name_prefix` is not available anymore](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/table_name_prefix/class).

Comment: You might be looking for `Multitenacy`: There are a few good [RailsCasts](http://railscasts.com/episodes?utf8=%E2%9C%93&search=multitenancy), [gems](http://www.plugingeek.com/categories/activerecord-multitenant-apps-ruby) and [books](http://rubyonrailsbook.com/multi-tenancy-with-rails.html) on that subject, it's much deeper than you might initially assume.